# Specman debugging OS11 in gen

Tags: specman

I'm getting OS 11 failure in a gen action. The constraints for this gen action are intensive, and it's too complex to debug.

How can we debug this failure and determine the source of this OS 11?

Comment: Have you tried the constraint debugger?  Specman has a dedicated debugger for constraints that is found in the Specview GUI.

Comment: The problem is that the OS11 is inside a CFS, i'm running in interpreted mode but it doesn't show any usefull information.

Comment: It indicates the original gen action as being the problem.

Comment: Yeah, Specman's constraint errors suck.  I don't have access to Specview right now, but can't you pause the constraint process right before running that constraint and then step it somehow?  (I forget the details.)  Anyways, this could get you close to knowing what is failing.  The alternative is that if you have ready access to all the constraints, you can use binary search to find the offender. Comment out half of the pertinent constraints, run and see if it fails.  Rinse, lather, repeat.

Comment: Kamil, please contact Cadence support for this issue. they can assist with reading the logs and understand the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An OS 11 error probably means you're trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer. Make sure you load your code (not compile it) to see where this is happening (this applies to all OS 11 errors and not just the ones in constraints). Compiled code removes a lot of debug information (to run faster), making it difficult to trace the exact portion of *e* code that is causing the problem.

Specman provides a great constraint debugger that can assist you further. I don't know the commands by heart but you have to set a break point when the failing CFS (connected field set) is being generated. Search for `break on gen` in the documentation.